# VLC plays videos with audio dropouts

Tags: sound, video, vlc

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I use VLC to play DVDs and videos. Audio dropouts occur when playing DVDs and videos. Can someone tell me how to fix the problem.

Comment: Ok, this is probably a stupid answer. Have you deleted VLC and reinstalled it? You can try using Synaptic to fully remove the package by pressing “Mark for Complete Removal”, then you can reinstall it with its dependencies. It’s ok if that doesn’t work, but it worked for me a while ago. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Without success.

Comment: Does it happen *only* in VLC? Also please [edit] and post hardware specifications and the audio output being used.